# How to close a process that just doesn't shut down?

Tags: process, uninstall, kill

I am trying to uninstall qbittorrent but it just doesn't shut down. I tried killing the process both in Win 7 and using Process XP but it's still lingering. Any ideas on how to kill processes like these?

Comment: Boot into a miminal configuration then uninstall the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSkill is the best program to kill things like this it is from sysinternals

EDIT
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx

Once you have download it extract it to windows/system32
Open task manager by right click desktop bar and open task manager
Click on processes then click view, select columns then click on pid and press ok
Open command prompt then type pskill -t pid

Comment: I just tried it but it says pskill is not recognized.

Comment: did you extract it to /windows/system32? if it not there you cant run it directly, you would need to go to the directory you extracted it to which in win7 and above is general download/pskill

Comment: @JoanVenge - We need more information then telling us "it doesn't work" are you sure you providing the entire path to the program when it attempted to run it?

Comment: Sorry I did extract it there, but when I run I only used like Andrew showed: pskill -t 10700 in my case.

Comment: When it says not recognised that generally is the file can not be found in default path in this case windows/system32 or local path, im guessing it never extracted tot eh correct location, extract it again to default location which is where the zip is download, in command prompt cd to the location then rerun

Comment: Mine is here: C:\Windows\System32\PSTools, should it be directly inside system32?

Comment: yes sorry i should have explained better

Comment: I copied the files directly and now it worked except it asked for Agreement which I accepted and now it seems to hang the cmd, not frozen but waiting, but the process is still there.

Comment: If it hanging you might have very stubborn file and you might need to look at linux live cd to delete the file, or it might be causing a high system usage such it will be slow, if it restart right after going you have fairly serious problem and you will need linux

Comment: Ok I restarted and uninstalled it. Really annoying some apps do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't kill a process through the taskmanager, its likely that the program runs as a service.

Open your startmenu and search for `services.msc` then look for a service named qbittorrent and stop the service. If you want to prevent it from running, edit the service, and set the startup type to manual (you can start it) or disabled (program can't be launched).

Note that if you fire up the program chances are high it will alter the service and restore its settings. Given that you want to uninstall the program, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks just checked but it's not there, there is only quality windows under q.

Answer (score 0):

[DTaskManager](http://www.dimio.altervista.org/eng/#DTaskManager) is a good free software for this.